# How can I make a full height div ontop of a Bootstrap4 grid (Slide out from right side of container edge)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm learning bootstrap 4.

I want a div positioned ontop of the grid (content underneath), all to the right side of the grid (not the screen), 200px width and covering 100% height, fixed.

I've tried several solutions with the markup and CSS - but I can only get it positioned in the right of the user screen.

Bonus info: Next, I want to use jQuery to make it slide in and out - but I think I can figure that out myself. But it's the positioning which is giving me a headache.

At the moment I'm just experimenting with a total basic bootstrap grid:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      Header row
    </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      Middle row
    </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      Bottom row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a wireframe to further explain what I am trying to achieve.
https://ibb.co/zFxJJZT

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It's hard to give a specific answer to your question because I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, perhaps you could provide a wireframe or an example.

Comment: Hi! 
Maybe this explains it better. If not, please let me know :-)

Edit - new link: https://ibb.co/zFxJJZT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to absolute position the div you want to put atop the container. When making a div position `absolute` you also need to make the parent relatively positioned. You should [read this](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) to understand better.

So, just add the div in the container and make it position absolute. In Bootstrap 4 you can do this by adding a class called `position-absolute`. Also to make the div not position itself according to the body, add a `position-relative` class to `container` div.

```css
.side-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container position-relative bg-dark text-white col-6">
  <div class="position-absolute side-bar bg-primary">
side
</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      Header row
    </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      Middle row
    </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      Bottom row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```